# Android Studio ---- The path is not writable. Please choose a new location

Tags: android

I just installed Android Studio and want to start a new project. But it showed the following error message:

> The path XYZ is not writable. Please choose a new location

How should I fix this problem?

[image]

Comment: You have to provide a disk location where the application can write into memory..such as document, desktop or any user specific path.

Answer (score 3):

The most likely explanation is that the directory and all its files are owned by a different user account on the system. Normally the "Clear Read-Only Access" dialog will fix up read permission problems if it's possible to do so; if it's not (because the files are owned by another user), the dialog will refuse to let you click the OK button.

You can confirm this by using the ls command from the MacOS terminal. Here's an example from a random project of mine.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue. Running Android Studio as an administrator worked for me. If this is a possibility for you and you did not do it before, give it a whirl.

Answer (score 1):

I got that error on windows because the initial project location was `C:\`. But the problem was solved when I made a folder and gave that path:

`C:\repo\myApplication`

Answer (score 0):

Myself also faced the same problem because , I have changed the permission of that drive from x:\ -> properties -> security . Once I have given full control for my user option(one among 4 options in security) and reopening the Android studio , it didn't post that warning again. So, before you try this option , please verify the security details of drive and make sure that it doesn't affect your further operations regarding security.

Answer (score 0):

I was having this same problem, then I plugged in a flash-drive. It allowed for a place to store the files with a location that did not have white space, was empty, and had enough room to store everything I needed. The flash was the only way I found on my computer to store the files where the path was writable. Hope this helps someone.

Comment: Can you please explain how did this solved the problem

Answer (score 0):

You can create that folder (or those folders) yourself, then run the installer again.